# Библиотека для работы с большими числами в C

Tags: c, длинная-арифметика

Какие есть библиотеки больших чисел на C. Необходима поддережка 256 & 512 & 1024 битные числа. Спасибо.

Comment: https://github.com/kokke/tiny-bignum-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

гугл по словам "binint c" выдает кучу-кучу. 
Но можно начать с классики - [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). Даже на [википедии есть пример](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library).

Рядом, на SO есть примеры, как люди [пишут свое](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20783/biginteger-implementation-in-c-supporting-addition-and-multiplication).

Comment: стоит оговориться, что gmp гвоздями прибита к gcc... а в вики есть ещё целый [список](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software) альтертнатив.

Comment: думаю, что 1024 битные можно и на коленке сделать

Comment: особой разницы, писать для чисел в 256, 1к или 16к бит — в общем-то нет, а вот что писать и какие требования к эффективности — есть, например, сложение-умножение сделать на коленке — не сложно, а вот деление я бы на вскидку своё писать не стал бы, пока совсем не припрёт...

Answer (score 0):

Как-то мне тоже понадобилась длинная арифметика. Но использовать GMP было нельзя, так как длинная арифметика нужна была для микроконтроллеров без операционной системы и кучи. Пришлось написать свою библиотеку С++ шаблонов для работы с длинными целыми числами. Вот ссылка:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/muntl/?source=frontpage&position=5

Там в архиве есть и описание на русском языке. Но это не Си, а шаблоны С++.